# Benefits of CucumberJS w/ Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, cucumberjs

I am trying to understand why Cucumber would be used with Protractor. I understand that the Gherkins is a plus because it makes the tests easier to read, but cant tests be kicked off and written with pure protractor? What other benefits does it provide?

Comment: protractor is just a tool for web automation.But you need any testing framework like cucumber/jasmine/mocha to write and maintain your tests.And also testing frameworks are used for making assertion which will decide whether the test has been passed/failed.

Comment: But cant protractor be used to write tests? How does Cucumber play a part?

Comment: the below link will help you understand the use for a test automation framework http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/why-do-we-need-test-automation-framework/

Comment: Sudharsan is correct.  Protractor is the framework, it still needs to integrate a testing library to perform assertions.